# GCM receiver not working when app idle for sometime but works fine when app is on

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM Push Notifications in my application and it is working fine. Receiver receives when app is in foreground or in background. But the Receiver is not receiving on some specific phones when the app is in background. What am I doing wrong?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"    />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTER" />
<permission
    android:name="com.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:killAfterRestore="false"        
    android:allowClearUserData="false">

 <receiver
        android:name="com.testapp.ExternalReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
            <action android:name="com.testapp" />

            <category android:name="com.testapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.testapp.GCMService" />

 </application>
```

**ExternalReceiver**

```
public class ExternalReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver  {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
             ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                        GCMService.class.getName());

             GCMService.context = context;
                // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
                startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

                setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);      
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are these device's able to register on GCM or not ??
can you get registration key of them ?

Comment: Yes, i can register and send and receive messages when app is running.

Comment: I am unable to receive only when application is in background. This is occurring in huawei honor phones, i have tried with multiple devices.

Comment: Then in this case I guess these devices are blocking background data , you should enable it from device settings

Comment: other applications run fine even in background. Are there any setting we can define in manifest so that it is blocked?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.testapp.ExternalReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
            <action android:name="com.testapp" />

            <category android:name="com.testapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

To this:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
            <action android:name="com.testapp" />

            <category android:name="com.testapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Just one line!!!